# opencv face recognition prediction error

Tags: c++, opencv, face-recognition

I have stumbled upon an exception in my application that I am unable to get rid of...

I am trying to write a simple image face recognition program with all three face recognition algorithms(Eigen, Fisher and LBPH).

The unchandled exception is caused by line :

```
Fisher_prediction = Fisher_model->predict(crop);
```

and theerror message says: `Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFDB3A49D in FaceRecognition.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000002782B0.`

and is caused by: `msvcr110d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo) Line 152 C++`

Any sugestions where am I going wrong??

here is the rest of the code:

```
Mat frame = imread("1.jpg");

    // Apply the classifier to the frame
    if (!frame.empty()) {

        cvtColor(frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        equalizeHist(frame_gray, frame_gray);

        // Detect faces
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

        // Set Region of Interest
        cv::Rect roi_b;
        cv::Rect roi_c;

        size_t ic = 0; // ic is index of current element
        int ac = 0; // ac is area of current element

        size_t ib = 0; // ib is index of biggest element
        int ab = 0; // ab is area of biggest element

        // Iterate through all current elements (detected faces)
        for (ic = 0; ic < faces.size(); ic++) {

            roi_c.x = faces[ic].x;
            roi_c.y = faces[ic].y;
            roi_c.width = (faces[ic].width);
            roi_c.height = (faces[ic].height);

            ac = roi_c.width * roi_c.height; // Get the area of current element (detected face)

            roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
            roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
            roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
            roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);

            ab = roi_b.width * roi_b.height; // Get the area of biggest element, at beginning it is same as "current" element

            if (ac > ab) {

                ib = ic;
                roi_b.x = faces[ib].x;
                roi_b.y = faces[ib].y;
                roi_b.width = (faces[ib].width);
                roi_b.height = (faces[ib].height);
            }

            crop = frame(roi_b);
            cv::resize(crop, res, Size(img_width, img_height), 0, 0, INTER_LINEAR); // This will be needed later while saving images
            cvtColor(crop, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY); // Convert cropped image to Grayscale

            Point pt1(faces[ic].x, faces[ic].y); // Display detected faces on main window - live stream from camera
            Point pt2((faces[ic].x + faces[ic].height), (faces[ic].y + faces[ic].width));
            //rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);

            /* Calculate the position for annotated text */
            int pos_x = std::max(roi_b.tl().x - 10, 0);
            int pos_y = std::max(roi_b.tl().y - 10, 0);

        if(createdFisher) {
            Fisher_prediction = Fisher_model->predict(crop);
            QString Fisher_qs = QString::number(Fisher_prediction);
            /* Create the text we will annotate the box with */
            string Fisher_text = format("Prediction Fisherfaces = %d", Fisher_prediction);
            putText(frame, Fisher_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
            /* Draw a green rectangle around the detected face */
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, MATCH_COLOR, 1);
            ui.txtConsole->appendPlainText(QString("Fisherfaces - " + Fisher_qs));
        }
        if(createdEigen) {
            Eigen_prediction = Eigen_model->predict(crop);
            QString Eigen_qs = QString::number(Eigen_prediction);
            /* Create the text we will annotate the box with */
            string Eigen_text = format("Prediction Eigenfaces = %d", Eigen_prediction);
            putText(frame, Eigen_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
            /* Draw a green rectangle around the detected face */
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, MATCH_COLOR, 1);
            ui.txtConsole->appendPlainText(QString("Eigenfaces - " + Eigen_qs));
        }
        if(createdLBPH) {
            LBPH_prediction = LBPH_model->predict(crop);
            QString LBPH_qs = QString::number(LBPH_prediction);
            /* Create the text we will annotate the box with */
            string LBPH_text = format("Prediction LBPH = %d", LBPH_prediction);
            putText(frame, LBPH_text, Point(pos_x, pos_y), FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN, 1.0, CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2.0);
            /* Draw a green rectangle around the detected face */
            rectangle(frame, pt1, pt2, MATCH_COLOR, 1);
            ui.txtConsole->appendPlainText(QString("Linear Binary Patern Histogram - " + LBPH_qs));
        }
        }

        putText(frame, text, cvPoint(30, 30), FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.8, cvScalar(0, 0, 255), 1, CV_AA);
        imshow("original", frame);

        if (!crop.empty()) {
            imshow("detected", crop);
        }
        else
            destroyWindow("detected");
    }

    int c = waitKey(0);
```

All the necessary #include and variables along with the classifier are initialised at the start of the program.

Comment: where and how do you create the recognizers ?

Comment: @berak - the recognisers are created in other part of my program... they work grand, I know because i am running a live stream face recognition in the other part... I create them like that:   Fisher_model = createFisherFaceRecognizer(); Eigen_model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(); LBPH_model = createLBPHFaceRecognizer();

Comment: if you don't have: Ptr<FisherFaceRecognizer> Fisher_model  then ...

Comment: also, where's the error msg ?

Comment: @berak -  I do have those, cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> Fisher_model;
 cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> Eigen_model;
 cv::Ptr<cv::FaceRecognizer> LBPH_model;

Comment: out of ideas, besides this: don't pass color images to the prediction, but grayscale ones.

Comment: @berak - I know... Thanks anyway for intrest

Comment: @berak - I was actually passing a color image to prediction... I have not realised it til now... but it still did not get rid of the exception

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing wrong is that I was passing a picture to the facerecogniser that was not resized (I am using pictures that are 200x200px in my database) , so the algorithm could not do the face recognition based on a larger resolution image than the one that is in a database.